# Is there a quick trick to see $\mathbb{E}[\theta|L=l] = \mathbb{E}_{\Lambda}\left[ \mathbb{E}[\theta|\Lambda, L=l] | L=l \right]$ without expanding?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

As in the title, why is $\mathbb{E}[\theta|L=l] = \mathbb{E}_{\Lambda}\left[ \mathbb{E}[\theta|\Lambda, L=l] | L=l \right]$?

A quick glance says tower rule, but not so obvious how is it applied here.

**EDIT:** $\mathbb{E}_{\Lambda}$ just means that the expectation is taken wrt to $\Lambda$ (uses the density of $\Lambda$). Further, if you expand these expectations (as in, write everything in terms of integrals), then everything works out, they are equal. But the equality was given as a one-liner (in an otherwise spoon-fed class) to me, that makes me think there is a quick trick/ property that was used here.

Comment: What is $\Lambda$ and what distinguishes $\mathbb{E}_\Lambda$ from $\mathbb{E}$ in your notation?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I clarified, and changed the question a bit.

Comment: I still don't see the difference between $\mathbb{E}_\Lambda$ and $\mathbb{E}$.  If there's no change of probability spaces, then an expectation is just an expectation.

Comment: @BrianMoehring It was already written like that where I found this expression, but sometimes when there is a room for confusion I have seen people indicating which variable are we integrating out (take the expectation). I think I see this a lot in statistics, but I don't have another explicit example in mind.

Comment: I mean, sure, in the RHS the outer expectation can only be for $\Lambda$, but if it was my first time seeing the term it would take me a few seconds to rule out $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the tower rule:
$$\mathbb{E}[\theta\mid L] =\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[\theta\mid\Lambda, L]\mid L\Big]$$
From where:
$$\mathbb{E}[\theta\mid L=l] = \mathbb{E}\Big[ \mathbb{E}[\theta\mid\Lambda, L]\mid L=l \Big]=\mathbb{E}\Big[ \mathbb{E}[\theta\mid\Lambda, L=l]\mid L=l \Big]=$$
$$=\mathbb{E}_{\Lambda}\Big[ \mathbb{E}[\theta\mid\Lambda, L=l]\mid L=l \Big]$$